# VBA How to prevent the main file from being formatted if the source file folder is empty?

Tags: vba, excel

I have 4 macros running one after the other:

**1st - looks for the latest (newest) file in the source file location: In here I have a problem, because if there is no file at the location (C:\Source File) then, the file that is currently opened (main file) is formatted in the way that only the source file should be.** I don't need message box and I don't want this (Main) file to be formatted if there is no source data file in the location.

```
'1
Option Explicit

Sub OpenLatestFile()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim MyPath As String
    Dim MyFile As String
    Dim LatestFile As String
    Dim LatestDate As Date
    Dim LMD As Date
    MyPath = "C:\Source File\"
    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    MyFile = Dir(MyPath & "*.csv", vbNormal)
    If Len(MyFile) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No files were found...", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
        LMD = FileDateTime(MyPath & MyFile)
        If LMD > LatestDate Then
            LatestFile = MyFile
            LatestDate = LMD
        End If
        MyFile = Dir
    Loop
    Workbooks.Open MyPath & LatestFile
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**2nd Macro: Column Removals**

```
'2
Sub RemoveCols()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Alfa1 = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Range("X:AA,FA:I").Delete
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**3rd: Row Removal**

```
'3
Sub RemoveXYZ()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim lLRow As Long
    With Sheets(1)
        lLRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("C:C").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="XYZ"
        .Range("C2:C" & lLRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete xlShiftUp
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**4th: Copy formatted data from the source file into the Main file (which has Macros in it)**

```
'4
Option Explicit

    Sub TransferData()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim Last_Row1 As Long, Last_Row2 As Long
    Dim WB1 As Workbook, WB2 As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Set WB1 = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws1 = WB1.Sheets(1)
    Set WB2 = Workbooks("MainFile.xlsm")
    Set ws2 = WB2.Sheets("Master")
    Last_Row1 = ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Last_Row2 = ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    ws1.Range("A2:Z" & Last_Row1).Copy ws2.Range("A" & Last_Row2)
    WB2.Save
    Application.Quit
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    WB1.SaveChanges = False
    WB2.Save
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```

**Can you please advise how to maximize the efficiency of the above codes and make sure that the main file is not being formatted if there's no data in the "source file folder"?**

Moreover, the 1st macro is looking for the latest file (I would like to make sure that it doesn't pick up the file from the previous day) - any idea how to add a command "do not open source data if date is "minus 1 from today's date"?

Thanks
West

Comment: Any reason why they cant be one macro?

Comment: That's not the point. The point is that the first macro, formats the main document when there is no source docs in the "source docs folder".

Comment: **Any reason why they can't be one macro?** This *is* the point. You have `If Len(MyFile) = 0 Then.. Exit Sub`. If your code was in one macro, the `Exit Sub` here would solve your issue...

Comment: @ChristopherD. Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I combined all 4 macros and cleaned up a few pieces. The biggest change is setting your workbooks and worksheets earlier so the referencing was easier.

Is macro 2 affecting the source file or the master file? If each macro runs one after another, then it seems it would be the source file, which is what I did in the code below. If that is wrong you will need to move `.Range("X:AA,FA:I").Delete` out of the `With WS1` block and change it to `WS2.Range("X:AA,FA:I").Delete`.

As you can see, the first part of the code is almost identical. When `MyFile` is first assigned, it will be a zero-length string if there are no .csv files in the directory. The code then tests whether `MyFile` is in fact a zero-length string: `If Len(MyFile) > 0 Then`. So if no .csv files exist in `MyPath`, the `If` statement is executed and runs `Exit Sub`, which stops execution of the procedure. Because the code is all in one sub, the formatting code will not run if the folder is empty.

So to make this work you will need to stop the calls on macros 2-4 and replace macro 1 with the code below.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ProcessLatestFile()

    Dim MyPath As String
    Dim MyFile As String
    Dim LatestFile As String
    Dim LatestDate As Date
    Dim LMD As Date
    Dim lLRow As Long
    Dim Last_Row1 As Long, Last_Row2 As Long
    Dim WB1 As Workbook, WB2 As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Check for file
    MyPath = "C:\Source File\"
    MyFile = Dir(MyPath & "*.csv", vbNormal)
    If Len(MyFile) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No files were found...", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
        LMD = FileDateTime(MyPath & MyFile)
        If LMD > LatestDate Then
            LatestFile = MyFile
            LatestDate = LMD
        End If
        MyFile = Dir
    Loop

    'Open Source File
    Set WB1 = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & LatestFile)
    Set ws1 = WB1.Sheets(1)
    Set WB2 = Workbooks("MainFile.xlsm")
    Set ws2 = WB2.Sheets("Master")

    'Format Source File
    With WS1
        .Range("X:AA,FA:I").Delete
        lLRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("C:C").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="XYZ"
        .Range("C1:C" & lLRow).Offset(1,0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete xlShiftUp
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

    'Copy data
    Last_Row1 = ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Last_Row2 = ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    ws1.Range("A2:Z" & Last_Row1).Copy ws2.Range("A" & Last_Row2)

    'Clean Up
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    WB1.SaveChanges = False
    WB2.Save
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.Quit
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Christopher. I will test it this week and get back to you. West